# trouble making rt tickets in perl

Tags: perl, rest, rt

I'm new to Perl and really struggling to understand how to do this.  I'm trying to create a ticket using the Perl module RT::Client::REST, here's my code so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use RT::Client::REST;
use Rt::Client::REST::Ticket;

my $rt = RT::Client::REST->new(
    server => ($ENV{RTSERVER} || 'http://rt.myrturl.com'),
);
$rt->login(
    username => 'user',
    password => 'pass',
);

my $ticket = RT::Client::REST::Ticket->new(
    rt => $rt,
    queue => "General - unassigned",
    subject => "Perl Create Ticket Test",
);

$ticket->store("I'm a ticket");
```

This code isn't making the ticket and I don't know how to get any kind of good debugging output from Perl.  Based on the documentation for RT::Client::REST at [RT::Client::REST::Ticket](http://search.cpan.org/~jlmartin/RT-Client-REST/lib/RT/Client/REST/Ticket.pm), $ticket->store() should create the ticket.  Does anyone have any familiarity with the module that might be able to help?

EDIT:
I added print statements throughout the code as so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use RT::Client::REST;
use Rt::Client::REST::Ticket;

my $rt = RT::Client::REST->new(
    server => ($ENV{RTSERVER} || 'http://rt.myrturl.com'),
);
print "1";
$rt->login(
    username => 'user',
    password => 'pass',
);
print "2";
my $ticket = RT::Client::REST::Ticket->new(
    rt => $rt,
    queue => "General - unassigned",
    subject => "Perl Create Ticket Test",
);
print "3";
$ticket->store("I'm a ticket");
```

The following error is thrown on the print 2 line:

```
Unknown code ref type given ''. Check your usage & try again at CreateRTTicket.pl line 19
```

Comment: do you mean the status field in RT::Client::REST::Ticket?

Comment: Re Perl debugging: `perl -d myScript.pl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to create tickets in RT from a script, there are two other approaches you should probably try before going straight at the underlying REST code.

If you want to call the REST API, take a look at the examples [on the community wiki](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST), specifically starting with [the Perl example](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST#Perl).

Depending on what you're doing, you can also call the [rt command-line client](http://bestpractical.com/docs/rt/latest/rt.html) from your code. You can find docs by typing

```
/opt/rt4/bin/rt help
```

Once you get that working, you can call it from your script using `system` or backticks from Perl. You can also install the rt command-line client on a separate machine using the [stand-along module](https://metacpan.org/module/RT%3a%3aClient%3a%3aCLI) and can call RT from there.

Answer (score 1):

Make a private copy of RT/client/REST.pm in your tree if you haven't already. Open it an editor and find `sub _submit`. See these lines in it:

```
# Then we send the request and parse the response.
#DEBUG(3, $req->as_string);
my $res = $self->_ua->request($req);
#DEBUG(3, $res->as_string);
```

Uncomment the `DEBUG` lines, and try your script again. You should see your raw HTTP request and responses appear on STDERR, which should help with debugging.

I found this by starting with the 'store' routine you mentioned, and just tracing from there to find where the raw HTTP response and request were happening.

A tool like the [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) for Chrome could help you test and refine the raw HTTP transactions. Once you have it working at the raw HTTP level, you'll perhaps have an understanding how to proceed at the Perl API level.

---

Also, as [the docs illustrate](https://metacpan.org/module/RT%3a%3aClient%3a%3aREST), you should be catching and checking your exceptions. You could be die'ing before you even get to the `store` call. For that matter, as a temporary debugging measure, you could `print` something in between each call, as a simple reality check that the script has advanced past each step.

Comment: Your suggested changes did not produce any different output for me

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the private, modified copy of RT::Client::REST, and not the global copy? You could try dumping out  the global `@INC` and `%INC` variables to be sure. Adding an explicit `use lib` line pointing to your private directory may be required. if you are the only user on the server, you could also jus t modify the gobal copy.  Once you are certain you are modifying the copy of the module that's actually in use, feel free to add other `DEBUG` or just plain `warn` calls to the code to narrow things down.

Comment: Ok, I'm not very familiar with Perl so where might I find the global copy?

Comment: Add to your code: `use Data::Dumper; warn Dumper (\%INC)`. It will contain the paths to all the modules you've got loaded. If are loading the global copy, you'll see the path to it.

Comment: that doesn't change my output either

Comment: Maybe your `STDERR` is going somewhere other than your terminal. That would affect both cases. Try replacing `warn Dumper` with `print Dumper`.

Comment: that didn't work either.  all that prints is "Found" every time.  Which seems to be outputted somewhere in the authentication process.